Error connecting to PowerBI Service using Powershell commandlets with Service Principal Approach
I am getting the following error when trying to connect to PowerBI Service using the PowerShell commandlets. It works fine when I try to call Power BI REST APIs from Python. Any inputs will be appreciated.
$secrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -AsPlainText -Name $secretName

$secrets = $secrets | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$credential = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $clientId, $secrets

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Tenant $tenantId -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential


